# How to check if my product's expiring date is 3 days or less after today?

Tags: php

I have a product expiring list. In this list I will show only the products that are 3 days before expiration. That means that today 18-10-2011 the products that the list will show are products who have an expiring date until 22-10-2011.

I get the product's expiring date using

```
$input = date('d-m-y', strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'liksi', true)));
```

My thought is having something like

```
if product_expiring_date (this is $input) is 3 days or less after current date 
then { }
```

How can I check this with "real code" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do

```
$expires = strtotime(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'liksi', true)); 
$input = date('d-m-y', $expires);
if ($expires < strtotime('+3 days')) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check `$input < strtotime` ?

Comment: Nope, `$expires` is an int, `$input` is a string. That's why I separated the statement into two parts...

Comment: I don't understand the role of the $input

Comment: It may have no purpose - I only left it there because I assumed you needed the value as a string for something else as well (displaying on a page maybe?) - if you don't need it, just get rid of the second line...